# Android centre title with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I currently have a navigation drawer with a toolbar that has a title, i wish to centre this title within the toolbar but the toolbar does not seem to take into consideration the drawer icon as you can see in the following picture.

[image: Off centre]

whereas when i use the same toolbar layout for other activities that are not inside the navigation drawer the title is centred perfectly, as show in this picture:

[image]

So how do i get it to take into account this icon?

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.App.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to understand that Toolbar widget extends [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) class, and it has it's own [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.LayoutParams.html).

So you do not require RelativeLayout inside Toolbar, and need to add just single line with TextView.

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

And final xml should look like this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/Theme.App.AppBarOverlay" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.App.PopupOverlay" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chitrang you made my day

Comment: I need to show imageview and TextView inside Toolbar, how can i do that

Comment: What if i have to use RelativeLayout mandatory. As i have many 2 more images in toolbar ?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `RelativeLayout`, then change your `TextView` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.App.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

After that call `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled`, to remove the original title, in the `onCreate` method of your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ...
    }
}
```

This is the result obtained:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to change  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in Textview.....

Comment: All this does is stretch the text view to the width of the toolbar, which as i have highlighted does not account for the icon, so it is still off centre

Comment: match_parent and set its gravity (not layout_gravity) to center too

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam again this doesn't solve the problem of it being offset, as the entire layout is not taking into consideration the width of the drawer button.

Comment: Ah. I think there is a space for navigation button where you could not surpass. You should read toolbar's source code for more information and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. try to use this code into your xml ,  your code with few changes :

[image]

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />
```

Use this for each activity.
This will makes sure that your text would cover the entire space next to the icon and center the text within it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

--------Nav_Drawer layout 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text="Android Studio"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="android.studio@android.com" android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it did not work either of the answers. Instead, I just put to the TextView a margin start of **-40dp** which is the icon width of the drawer. And it's working great.
Maybe it's useful for someone